# Similar alternative for GetComponent on godot

Tags: c#, sockets, godot

Is there an alternative for `GetComponent` in [Godot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godot_(game_engine)) as I need to access other components?

Here's what we have in [Unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_(game_engine)):

```
socket = GetComponent<SocketIOComponent>();
```

I'm trying to convert Unity C# files to Godot C#.

Comment: Godot is not based on a Component System. You can build one if you really want to, I have an example [elsewhere](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/193888/how-to-make-a-component-solution-in-godot-similar-to-unitys). However, this is [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info), tell you what is you are trying to do, and we can tell you how to do it in Godot. Given that your line has `SocketIOComponent`, I'm guessing something network related. So, I'll point you to the [MultiplayerAPI](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_multiplayerapi.html).

Comment: See also: [StreamPeerTCP](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_streampeertcp.html), [TCP_Server](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_tcp_server.html),  [PacketPeerUDP](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_packetpeerudp.html), [UDPServer](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_udpserver.html).

Comment: On the flip side, perhaps what you want is some way to have an object available everywhere, but not static. That is, a singleton. See [AutoLoad](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/step_by_step/singletons_autoload.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [GetNode](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_node.html#class-node-method-get-node) method and cast the result to type of the node. You'll need to specify NodePath since Godot uses String paths to specify references to other nodes instead of the more complex system used by Unity under the hood.

How Godot handles composition is a bit different from Unity. In Unity you might have a single `GameObject` with multiple components, but to achieve the same in Godot you would have a parent Node with multiple child nodes that work like components would in Unity. To refer to these nodes ("components") from parent one would do so with `GetNode` and specify the path to the node and cast it to the type of the node, i.e., `RigidBody`.

Probably the most Unityish approach you could do is something that's very similar to dragging component references to public fields on components. In Godot you can do something like that by [exporting](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/scripting/c_sharp/c_sharp_differences.html#export-keyword) NodePath variables which allow you to specify a path to a specific node in the node hierarchy and then use that with GetNode to get the actual "component".

Comment: You will commonly see ``get_node("name")`` as ``$name``.

Comment: Using string references is generally bad practice as they break the moment name of the node its path changes. Hence it's better to export reference to a node using its type (Godot 4.x) or using NodePath which can be assigned from the editor.

Answer (score 0):

I use this helper, it has its own trade-offs but provides a similar interface to getComponent from unity:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Godot;

public static class NodeHelper{
    // get all scripts of type under and including node, internal children is to include sub nodes children. returns empty if none found.
    public static IEnumerable<Type> getComponents<Type>(this Node node, bool internal_children=false){
        return node.GetChildren(internal_children).Append(node).OfType<Type>();
    }
    // get first script of type under and including node, internal children is to include sub nodes children. will return default if none found.
    public static Type getComponent<Type>(this Node node, bool internal_children=false)  {
        return node.getComponents<Type>(internal_children).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```